# defstruct - :read-only is not read only

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In the CLHS I read for `:read-only x`: "When x is true, this specifies that this slot cannot be altered; it will always contain the value supplied at construction time."

Bit I can do this (CCL, SBCL):

```
CL-USER> (defstruct foo
           (one 0 :read-only t))
FOO
CL-USER> (defparameter *foo* (make-foo))
*FOO*
CL-USER> *foo*
#S(FOO :ONE 0)
CL-USER> (setf (slot-value *foo* 'one) 1)
1 (1 bit, #x1, #o1, #b1)
CL-USER> *foo*
#S(FOO :ONE 1)
```

Shouldn't changing this slot be prohibited by Lisp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification says:

> `setf` will not accept the reader *function* for this slot.

`slot-value` is not the reader function created by `defstruct`. The reader function is `foo-one` (unless you override the naming scheme with the `:conc-name` keyword). So you should get an error if you try to do

```
(setf (foo-one *foo) 1)
```

Comment: Indeed. It's not possible to set the slot using the reader.
Though the "it will _always_ contain" in the description is a bit missleading IMO.

Comment: @Manfred: it's not misleading.  In a conforming program it will indeed always contain the initial value.  In a nonconforming program it may not: it may indeed contain hundreds of tiny daemons and orange smoke

Answer (score 5):

`slot-value` is not how you access the fields of an object whose class was defined with `defstruct`.  Such objects do not portably have named slots at all: they have named *accessors*.

Some implementations give the fields of such objects names, and may also allow access to them with `slot-value`: such behaviour is entirely nonportable however.

If you work within the language defined by the standard then you should not be able to modify the value of a structure field defined with a `:read-only` option.